# Tabelas de log deveriam ter Foreign Keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tive um caso em meu serviço esses dias em que não era possível excluir um registro pois o mesmo era referenciado pela tabela de `log`. Logicamente o que gerou um chamado para a área de TI resolver.

Mas tal caso me fez pensar. Apesar que por padrão evito a exclusão de registros, geralmente inativo o registro, nesse caso preciso excluir um registro.
Então nesse caso preciso apagar os registros no log.

Ao invés de eu ficar totalmente sem log do registro, seria melhor eu criar as tabelas de log sem FKs, e assim poder apagar os registros sem gerar erro de `foreign key`?

Ou melhor, haveria uma forma de eu checar a FK somente no momento que faço a inserção ou update nos registros da tabela?

Comment: A dúvida é interessante, mas a resposta provavelmente é "só depende de cada caso". Já vi ótimos sistemas que não usam FK pra absolutamente nada, pq a aplicação sabe como lidar com os dados. Por outro lado, log se é só log, não devia ter amarração com nada. Provavelmente você deve estar falando desses casos que por falta de se usar uma arquitetura de DB temporal, tudo que é editado é logado numa tabela separada (acho meio pobre, mas muitas vezes é o que se faz).

Comment: A pergunta que eu faria pro DBA é outra: pra que usar FK numa tabela dessas em vez de só armazenar o ID sem forçar um relacionamento? Você pode muito bem guardar o ID original e não fazer ele como FK.

Comment: @Bacco Não fazê-la uma FK não faz sentido. Pois caso um registro seja removido, todas as entradas na tabela de logs que faziam referência ao mesmo terão uma ID que não possui sentido algum. E, dependendo de como os IDs dos registros são gerados, corre-se o risco de um novo registro assumir um ID de outro registro já deletado.

Comment: @GabrielCandez não faz sentido no cenário específico que você imaginou, em outros pode fazer. Como eu disse no primeiro comentário, depende de cada caso. Se ele pode deletar o usuário, pode não ter problema nenhum o ID órfão. Pode ser muito bem que a informação do log seja importante para aferir coisas que não dependam do nome de quem fez. Só o caso real pode dizer o que faz ou não sentido.

Answer (score 5):

Para facilitar vamos supor que os registros que você citou são `Usuários` e você possui uma tabela para registrar as atividades dos mesmos. Essa tabela de atividades, chamemos ela de `logs` registra, digamos, a data/hora e o IP do usuário quando o mesmo faz login.

Caso um usuário seja removido da tabela `Usuários`, todas as entradas na tabela `logs` referentes ao mesmo perdem o sentido. Pois, sem o usuário ao qual se refere, as únicas informações que a mesma guarda é a data/hora e o IP.

Nesse caso, o ideal seria remover os logs também. O mesmo pode ser feito automaticamente pelo banco de dados usando `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Uma outra solução, a qual na minha opinião seria "mais correta", seria inativar o usuário. Por exemplo poderia utilizar um campo booleano chamado `inativo` na tabela `Usuários`. Você mantem os dados do usuário, o quê permite que os registros de atividades referentes ao mesmo continuem a possuir sentido.

Outra ideia seria também adicionar um registro de quando o usuário foi "inativado" e, após certo tempo, removê-lo completamente.

Answer (score 2):

> Ao invés de eu ficar totalmente sem log do registro, seria melhor eu
>   criar as tabelas de log sem FKs, e assim poder apagar os registros sem
>   gerar erro de foreign key?

Não faz sentido você ter um log órfão, ou seja, você deleta um usuário e ficar com o IdUsuario na tabela log, para que essa informação lê seria útil uma vez que não se pode sabe de quem é?
As FK sevem para relacionamos as tabelas e sabe que uma determinada informação tem um vínculo correspondente.

> Ou melhor, haveria uma forma de eu checar a FK somente no momento que
>   faço a inserção ou Update nos registros da tabela?

Você pode até criar uma tabela sem FK declarado explícito (ou seja, criar a coluna IdUsuario sem ser FK) e fazer o Insert ou Update verificando se tem o IdUsuario na sua tabela de log, mas se você deleta esse usuário cairá na questão de log órfão.

O que você pode fazer e deleta o registro da tabela LOG caso tenha um registro de FK e somente depois deleta seu registro da tabela correspondente.

Answer (score 2):

> Ao invés de eu ficar totalmente sem log do registro, seria melhor eu criar as tabelas de log sem FKs, e assim poder apagar os registros sem gerar erro de foreign key?

Guilherme, eu faria exatamente isto.

Eu não costumo criar com FK, pois a função do log que temos aqui na empresa é uma função de `auditoria`. Ou seja, temos uma tabela `TB_USUARIO` e uma `TB_USUARIO_AUD`, `TB_USUARIO_SOLICITACAO` e `TB_USUARIO_SOLICITACAO_AUD`.

E então se é necessário excluir o usuário, numa `rotina de expurgo`, por exemplo, não perderemos os dados, pois tudo estará na auditoria. 
Esta forma de trabalhar também ajuda muito na `performance da aplicação`, pois nas "TBs"` só estarão dados ativos que a aplicação pode manipular.